# Adding content from multiple XML with setSelectedDataAsync

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I am working on a Word addin to paste data stored in XML files into a Word document. I cannot find a way to paste data from multiple XML files one after another.

The code is below. I tried to somehow change the active selection within the function but did not succeed. The second XML will always paste over the first XML; I want the second XML to be pasted after the first XML. Ultimately I want one function to call various other functions which then each paste XML so I can create a modular document.

```
function A() {

    var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var myXML;
    myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', '../../OOXMLSamples/F1.xml', false);
    myOOXMLRequest.send();
    if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
        myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
    }
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, { coercionType: 'ooxml' });

    var myOOXMLRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var myXML;
    myOOXMLRequest.open('GET', '../../OOXMLSamples/F2.xml', false);
    myOOXMLRequest.send();
    if (myOOXMLRequest.status === 200) {
        myXML = myOOXMLRequest.responseText;
    }
    Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync(myXML, { coercionType: 'ooxml' });

}
```

Comment: As a matter of principle: If you need to do a thing multiple times, **never copy and paste code**. Make a function and call it two times with different parameters. Or make a loop.

Comment: Very important: which version of Word are you targeting? Or, put another way, which version of the Word API set? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets